# Is there a better way I could be receiving this input? C++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Currently just trying to edit some basic input to get rid of a singular '.' at the beginning of a line.
However, this only functions when I force EOF. My submission review for this assignment on the uni site seems to be getting stuck in the while loop and not outputting the result. The amount of input can be up to 1000 lines and I can't seem to think of how I could best receive this input without it getting stuck like this. main.cpp below:

Example input and output would be:

```
Input:
..hello
.hello
hello

Output:
.hello
hello
hello
```

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string inputLine;
    vector<string> vect;
    string s;
    string temp;

    while (getline(cin, s)) {
        vect.push_back(s);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)vect.size(); i++) {
        temp = vect[i];
        if (temp[0] == '.') {
            for (int k = 0; k < (int)temp.length(); k++) {
                temp[k] = temp[k + 1];
            }
        }
        vect[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < (int)vect.size(); j++) {
        cout << vect[j] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the input look like? Exactly? What do you mean by "force EOF"? FWIW your input handling looks decent in the general case. Not so sure about the other loops; they look more complicated than they need to be (given that you're using `std::string`s!) - are you sure it's not _those_ loops that are causing you problems?

Comment: `temp[k + 1]` You're lucky that reading the "one-past-the-end" character of a `std::string` is well-defined and guaranteed to give you `'\0'`; somehow I don't think this is what you intended, though.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica the input would be something like "..hello \n .hello \n hello\n" and should ouput ".hello \n hello \n hello \n"

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I'm pretty sure it's not the other loops, I can't see how the while loop would break without End of File being forced. By being forced I mean in terminal of ubuntu pressing Ctrl+D. and when I do this, the input comes out perfectly fine. However I need it to output without a forced EOF

Comment: @Cloppy If your goal is to simply remove the leading '.', you could simply use `find_first_not_of` and then `substr`.  You don't need to write loops for this.

Comment: Also, the correct header is `<string>`, not `<cstring>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is my goal for the first part of the assignment. to remove a singular . from the beginning of any line. However further on I need to implement in-input text editing commands that start with a '.' such as '.<' moves to beginning of document and '.k' deletes current line. Will what you're suggesting still be possible in this use case do you think?

Comment: I am just looking at the code you posted.  What you posted only deals with removing the '.' from the line of input.

Comment: @Cloppy I'm sure I said "exactly"....

Comment: @Cloppy I still don't know what "forced EOF" means. Your stream either goes into an EOF state, or it doesn't. That can happen because you're providing input from terminal and pressed Ctrl+D (Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Win), or because you're piping a file and there is no more file, or, or, or... If a stream doesn't go into EOF when it reaches the end of a piped file, something is very, very wrong. That's why we need to know precisely what your setup is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wouldn't even use that, since you're constrained to the period being leading. Just check `str[0]` and erase it if it's `'.'`. Job done.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica apologies, the input is just standard input from terminal. The contents (lines) of the input change significantly throughout the tests by the uni. I think fjardon may be correct about the uni expecting output after each line inputted, I will be able to test it in a few hours

Answer (score 1):

The tester of your program is probably opening a pipe and waiting for your program to output the first line before sending the second. A case of dead-lock.

If you want to ignore the `.` character you can use [std::basic_istream::peek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) to check if the line starts with this character and then simply [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) it. You may also want to flush your output for each line, using `std::endl` will do.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    while(std::cin) {
        if(std::cin.peek() == '.')
            std::cin.ignore();
        if(std::getline(std::cin, line))
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should output each line as each line is received? I will need to keep .'s in certain cases and will need the second . to remain in the case of two dots at the beginning so unfortunately I don't think that will help, but thanks a tonne for the suggestion about the dead-lock

Comment: See my update, you may also want to flush your output on each line...

Comment: Good catch, that's probably it.

Comment: Really could do with a requirements spec!!

Comment: I could give a requirements spec, but our uni is notorious for horribly written assignment specs, and it will confuse you more than anything. Also it is 3 pages long and a lot more complex than just what I'm asking here. But can still do it if needed

Comment: Does this peek and ignore only apply to the first '.' character? Or would it apply to all?

Comment: @Cloppy I guess what I meant was, _you_ could do with a requirements spec, from your Uni ;) I rarely receive any either :(